# Ubuntu Code of Conduct updated – should I?

Tags: community

I signed the [Ubuntu Code of Conduct](http://www.ubuntu.com/project/about-ubuntu/conduct) a good while back. I don't remember exactly when, and Launchpad doesn't tell me which version it is I've signed. Now there is a new version in the works. Should I sign the new one? Does it have any practical consequences either way?

Comment: This sort of discussion is a better fit for the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org).

Comment: It wasn't a discussion. It was a question. The documentation says something about certain services depending on the code of conduct. I think my people.ubuntu.com SFTP is one of them. But do I need to upgrade the code of conduct? Will older services become unavailable? I thought it was a somewhat easy question.

Comment: Please edit your question with these examples so that's more clear and then we can reopen it!

Answer (score 0):

*Do note that I'm adding this as a half-answer, because I can't fit this into a comment as a close reason. >.<*

As of right now, it is **not**, repeat **not** finalized.

Even then, any answer that this question might receive would be the following:

## Sign on your conscience.

Basically, what that boils down to is this:

Read it yourself. Figure out if you agree with it. If you do, sign it. Otherwise, don't.

<sub>That's all I have to say.</sub>

Comment: «All Ubuntu Members who have signed the Code of Conduct are granted SFTP access to a Web-accessible directory on people.ubuntu.com.» I have signed the old one. But what about the new one?

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad Because the new one isn't official yet, you don't have to worry until it is ready. **At the point it is ready for signing**, you have to decide. In short, you still have access to the SFTP people.u.c directory, because you signed and are a Ubuntu Member.